# Handle last iteration of asp.net repeater differently

Tags: asp.net

Is it possible to detect or use a different template in the asp.net repeater for the last iteration in the repeater?

If not I could just use a for loop but I'm curious if it can be done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know how many items you are expecting, you could use the e.Item.ItemIndex property to check if you are on the last item. Or, depending on what you are trying to do, you might be able to take advantage of the footer template.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly do it in this way following code will apply class "Last" at last item. you can apply your styling accordingly.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="rptrMainContent" runat="server">
  <ItemTemplate>
   <li class="<%#Container.ItemIndex==(rptrMainContent.DataSource as IList).Count-1?"Last":"" %>">
some text
   </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: For a similar solution but using Container.Parent see:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9742857/2340825

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes I do this by using PlaceHolder instances in my ItemTemplates. I.e.:

```
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phIsNotLastOne" runat="server">Is not last</asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:PlaceHolder id="phIsLastOne" runat="server">Is last</asp:PlaceHolder>
</ItemTemplate>
```

I usually have a variable to track the OnItemDataBound counter in my class as a protected class member:

```
protected int _bindCtr = 0;
```

Then in my ItemDataBound method:

```
protected void MyItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || 
        args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        ++this._bindCtr;
        this.phIsLastOne.Visible = this._bindCtr == this._dataSource.Count;
        this.phIsNotLastOne.Visible = this._bindCtr < this._dataSource.Count;
    }
}
```

More or less. Just make sure to have your data source assessible, and set your counter to 0 before binding.

Better to look at ItemIndex as suggested, versus approach above. 
Also the Repeater type has a DataSource property that is not strongly typed, but has a reference to your data source.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to create a local variable to hold count of items being bound to repeater.

Then when you're within OnItemDataBound event, check if current item index (e.Item.ItemIndex) is equal to the count - 1 (need -1 as item index is 0 based)

So...

```
if (e.Item.ItemIndex == (repeaterItemCount - 1))
{
    // Work on last item here...
}
```