# Change repeater li item class if first or last

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I'm using repeater to create dynamic ul li list

Is it possible to control class whether item is first or last?

Something like:

```
class="<%# if(Container.ItemIndex == 0)
   {
        class = ... 
   }
   ) %>"
```

by the way what does it really mean: `<%#` in ASP.NET

What is the difference between `<%#` and `<%=`?

Comment: Are you doing this in-line or with a code-behind page?  If you are loading the item from the code-behind page, it would be easy to reference the index 0 item and whatever the last index is.

Comment: There's also the CSS selectors of FIRST/LAST that you can use, I think they have poor support < IE8 (like half of CSS does)

Answer (score 57):

It is quite easy to determine whether the item is first or not (`Container.ItemIndex == 0`), but to determine whether the element is last or not you have to use a custom property which will be initialized right with data binding:

```
protected int ItemCount { get; set; }
```

Here is a repeater example:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
            <%# Container.DataItem %>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul>
    </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

here is an example of data binding:

```
public override void DataBind()
{
    var data = new string[] { "first", "second", "third" };
    this.ItemCount = data.Length;

    repeater.DataSource = data;
    repeater.DataBind();
}
```

and finally a helper method:

```
protected string GetItemClass(int itemIndex)
{
    if (itemIndex == 0)
        return "first";
    else if (itemIndex == this.ItemCount - 1)
        return "last";
    else
        return "other";
}
```

This will produce:

```
<ul>
    <li class="first">
        first
    </li>
    <li class="other">
        second
    </li>
    <li class="last">
        third
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you could also set the data class being bound, to have a field for; 1) ClassString (not good for design separation) 2)IsFirst/IsLast flag (does not scale well) 3) an index

Comment: I'm in need of this, but I don't quite get how to use it. Are you proposing the creation of a custom repeater object that extends repeater with the new property and overridden DataBind method? Otherwise, how does DataBind() actually get called in the first place since your repeater.DataBind() is within the DataBind() method itself?  Further note: I was able to get it working with some modifications. See my answer below...

Comment: @dadwithkids, no need to extend repeater, since `DataBind` method is defined in [`System.Web.UI.Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5e5992d(v=vs.110).aspx), and any control or even page can override it.

Comment: Surely `else if (itemIndex == this.ItemCount - 1)` doesn't work… `this` would be the Page! (If the method is defined on the page.)

Comment: @Protectorone why you think it does not?

Comment: @Alex: Ah, My mistake! I thought that `ItemCount` was a property of the repeater itself! I see now that you define it on the page, and update it manually. Apologies.

Answer (score 42):

I typically use something like the following:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptItems" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li<%# Container.ItemIndex == ((IList)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Count-1 ? " class='last'" : ""%>>
...
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Stamp of approval from Chuck Norris, what more can you want :) Thanks, helped me too!

Comment: Here is the VB.NET version: <%# IIf(Container.ItemIndex = CType((CType(Container.Parent, Repeater).DataSource), IList).Count - 1, True, False)%>

Comment: Here is the solution if the repeater's source is DataTable                            <%# Container.ItemIndex == ((System.Data.DataTable)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Rows.Count - 1 ? " " : "<li class='divider'></li> "%>

Answer (score 6):

If possible, I'd recommend using something like jQuery for this as it makes implementing this type of functionality very easy.  For example, you could have something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater id="MyRepeater" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate><table class="MyRepeater"></HeaderTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate><tr><td>My Data</td></tr></ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

$("table.MyRepeater tr:last").attr("class", "last");
```

Comment: That's how I would handle it too.

Comment: Note that if you have several similarly styled lists that need to do the same thing then use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) instead of [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/).

Comment: You can also use [`.addClass(...)`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) instead of `.attr(...)` to set the CSS-class.

Answer (score 3):

Try somwthing like this, if you are not using jQuery

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" CssClass='<%# Container.ItemIndex == 0 ? "first" : "notFirst" %>' runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: but it only handles first what if I want to add second condition for example if second or if last ?

Answer (score 3):

I modified nelsestu's solution and came up with:

```
<%# Container.ItemIndex == ((System.Data.DataTable)((Repeater)Container.Parent).DataSource).Rows.Count-1 ? "</div>" : string.Empty %>
```

Answer (score 1):

As for your question on the difference between <%= and <%#, please see the following links:

Code Render Blocks:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z(v=vs.71).aspx

Data Binding Expression Syntax:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bda9bbfx(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to use Alex's answer directly. Here are the modifications I made that worked for me. Using Alex's "repeater example" for the asp:Repeater tag, use this in the code behind:

```
private string[] data = new string[] { "first", "second", "third" };
protected int ItemCount { get; set; }

private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // normally one would fetch the data here right before binding like this:
    // data = SomeService.SomeMethodToGetData();
    repeater.DataSource = data;
    repeater.DataBind();
}

public override void DataBind()
{
    ItemCount = data.Count();
}

protected string GetItemClass(int itemIndex)
{
    if (itemIndex == 0)
        return "first";
    else if (itemIndex == this.ItemCount - 1)
        return "last";
    else
        return "other";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it like this for the last item

```
 Public m_recordCount As Integer
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ltrlTitle.Text = m_title

    Using Context As New MyEntities
        Dim m_lst = Context.getHotRecords(m_location).ToList
        m_recordCount = m_lst.count()

        rptListings.DataSource = m_lst
        rptListings.DataBind()
    End Using

End Sub
```

and here is how I use it in HTML markup

```
 <div <%# IIf(m_recordCount - 1 = Container.ItemIndex, "class='clearBorder'", "")%>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those needing this in VB, here's what works for me.

```
<span runat="server" class='divider' 
    Visible="<%# Container.ItemIndex < DirectCast(DirectCast(Container.Parent,Repeater).DataSource,List(Of IList)).Count()-1 %>">|</span>
```

I needed a divider to show for all items except for the last one.

Answer (score 0):

If your are using controls within your ItemTemplate you can do something like the following, add **OnItemDataBound** event.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RptId" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="OnItemDataBound">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="PnlCtrlItem">
      <%#Eval("Content") %>
    </asp:Panel>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void OnItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemIndex == 0)
      ((Panel) e.Item.FindControl("PnlCtrlItem")).CssClass = "first";
    //or the following to have your control indexed
    ((Panel) e.Item.FindControl("PnlCtrlItem")).CssClass = string.Format("item-{0}",e.Item.ItemIndex);
}
```