# How can I add "class" attributes to HTML elements?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, append

I have the following HTML. I want to add `class="last"` attributes to the final `li` elements in each list. How can I do this?

```
<div class="gpbscol">
<ul class="listl">
    <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
    <li>AMPLIFIERS</li>
    <li>ANALOG AUDIO PROCESSING</li>
    <li>MICROPHONE PREAMPLIFIERS</li>
    <li>MICROPHONES</li>
    <li>SPEAKERS/MONITORS</li>
    <li>STUDIO</li>
    <li>DIGITAL AUDIO PROCESSING</li>
    <li>CONSOLES, MIXERS</li>
    <li>DAWS/PERIPHERALS</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="audio"> 
   <ul class="listl">
    <li>DAWS/PERIPHERALS</li>
    <li>LOUDSPEAKERS — FOH</li>
    <li>RECORDERS/PLAYERS</li>
    <li>HEADPHONES</li>
    <li>MICROPHONES - WIRELESS CONVERTERS</li>
    <li>NETWORK AUDIO / CONTROL / SNAKES</li>
    <li>COMPUTER AUDIO INTERFACES</li>
    <li>INTERCONNECTS</li>
    <li>LOUDSPEAKERS — STAGE MONITORS</li>
    <li>ACOUSTIC TREATMENT</li>
    <li>MI PRODUCTS</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

So the final element might be

```
<li class="last">MI PRODUCTS</li>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier to do in ClientSide JavaScript? Why do you want to hand this on the server side?

Comment: What is the html in? A string variable, a web componant ect.

Comment: thats because the above structure is coming directly from the database, so i have to do the appending at server side only.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: its in string

Comment: I would recommend using HTML parser [Check html agility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Comment: @Abbas - Are you outputting the result or storing it back in the database?

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko: the results are coming from SQL Server and is used on page.. so i am outputting it from database

Comment: So your easiest option would be some javascript on the client side as John said.

Comment: @Abbas, is it coming back *as* HTML from the database, or are you creating the HTML dynamically with ASP.NET/code using rows from the db as the data source?

Comment: possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263696/change-repeater-li-item-class-if-first-or-last

Comment: Doesn't CSS have a :last-child selector too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be easier to do with jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.listl li:last").addClass("last");
});
```

And that's all, folks :)

Comment: @Smamatti: Thanks... such a subtle difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would be a styling issue. If I had no option for client side codes, I would go for CSS styling. You may consider this:

```
ul.listl li:last-child { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @JohnHartsock but if you want to do it your way you can use a variety of libraries which help you in querying html elements (DOM).

1. [Fizzler](http://code.google.com/p/fizzler/)
2. [Sharp-Query](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/)
3. [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] g=@"<div class=""gpbscol"">
<ul class=""listl"">
    <li>ACCESSORIES</li>
    <li>AMPLIFIERS</li>
    <li>ANALOG AUDIO PROCESSING</li>
    <li>MICROPHONE PREAMPLIFIERS</li>
    <li>MICROPHONES</li>
    <li>SPEAKERS/MONITORS</li>
    <li>STUDIO</li>
    <li>DIGITAL AUDIO PROCESSING</li>
    <li>CONSOLES, MIXERS</li>
    <li>DAWS/PERIPHERALS</li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class=""audio""> 
   <ul class=""listl"">
    <li>DAWS/PERIPHERALS</li>
    <li>LOUDSPEAKERS — FOH</li>
    <li>RECORDERS/PLAYERS</li>
    <li>HEADPHONES</li>
    <li>MICROPHONES - WIRELESS CONVERTERS</li>
    <li>NETWORK AUDIO / CONTROL / SNAKES</li>
    <li>COMPUTER AUDIO INTERFACES</li>
    <li>INTERCONNECTS</li>
    <li>LOUDSPEAKERS — STAGE MONITORS</li>
    <li>ACOUSTIC TREATMENT</li>
    <li>MI PRODUCTS</li>
   </ul>
</div>".Split(new string[]{"<li>"});

g[g.length-1]=g[g.length-1].replace("<li>","<li class='last' >");

string newString=String.Join("", g);
```

Comment: cannot create the .Split(new string[]{"<li>"}); instance on string array.. can you please check it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest of all, this is using HtmlAgilityPack;

```
TextWriter text = new StringWriter();
string set =  [html here];
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(set);
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//li[last()]");
HtmlAttribute attr;
attr = node.SetAttributeValue("class", "last");
doc.Save(text);
return text;
```

anyways thanks all for helping me.