# Using Directives

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

If I have a repeater going through a list of data to retieve the values I use

```
<%# Eval("current_item") %>
```

And with a bit of luck it outputs the information for "current_item"

However if I want to check if "current_item" equals 1 for instance, this will tell me whether to print the next lot of information. So how do I use that information to determine the output, effectivily I want to put that information into an variable.

```
<%# myInt = int.Parse(Eval("current_item")) %>
```

The above code is what I want to do really.

Then I will do something like this:

```
<% if (myInt == 1) { %>
<p>Information to display if myInt = 1</p>
<% } else { %>
<p>Other Information</p>
<% } %>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Eval("current_item").ToString().Equals("1")

Comment: Here is complete link about how to use repeater control  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719636(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: You can use the technique described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263696/change-repeater-li-item-class-if-first-or-last

Comment: I would advise you to use the Repeater's ItemDataBound event to do this kind of customisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used something similar to the following in a GridView:

```
<p>
    <asp:Label Visible='<%# ((int)Eval("current_item") == 1) %>' Text="This is the first item" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label Visible='<%# ((int)Eval("current_item") != 1) %>' Text="This is not the first item" runat="server" />
</p>
```

Give that a shot and see if it works for a Repeater too.

Comment: Done! Thanks, works perfectly. So I'm guessing that you cast the "current_item" to an int (well thats not a guess) however you then evaluate the statement as a boolean by stating whether its == 1?

Comment: Yes, that's it. I'm not sure whether the `(int)` cast is strictly necessary, but if this works, run with it :)