# Add class to last item

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [change repeater li item class if first or last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263696/change-repeater-li-item-class-if-first-or-last)

Im working on a .net website which I've never worked with before.

I have the following that outputs 4 divs...

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RT_Ranges" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="item">
            <h4>
                <%# Eval("Category_Name")%></h4>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Img") %>' runat="server" Height="92" Width="79" />
            <p>
                <%# Eval("des") %></p>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HL_More" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("nav") %>' runat="server">View More</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I want to add a class to the last DIV outputted from the above, is this possible and if so how would I do it?

Comment: can you use any clientside techniques, or you are restricted to use c#?
if you can, I will tell you a very easy solution using jQuery.

Comment: try with jQuery: `$("div.item:last").addClass("className")`; super simple

Comment: Helpful article: http://forums.asp.net/t/881301.aspx?Last+item+of+repeater

Answer (score 3):

You have your answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263696/change-repeater-li-item-class-if-first-or-last)

Make it like:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RT_Ranges" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
            <h4>
                <%# Eval("Category_Name")%></h4>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Img") %>' runat="server" Height="92" Width="79" />
            <p>
                <%# Eval("des") %></p>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HL_More" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("nav") %>' runat="server">View More</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

and on your code-behind:

```
protected string GetItemClass(int itemIndex)
{
if (itemIndex == this.ItemCount - 1)
        return "CSS_for_last_item";

}
```

Comment: Instead of `this.ItemCount` I had to use `RT_Ranges.Controls.Count`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on the server:

- in code behind after data is bound

or on the client:

- using pure CSS (see [`:last-child` selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_last-child.asp))
- using script (see [jQuery `:last-child` selector](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/))

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it. At least this is not easy.

If you need this class for styling reasons then use the `:last-child` pseudoclass instead and if you need this in javascript then there are other methods of getting the last child.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Panel` instead (which is rendered as div). Then you can use this  code to get the last item and find the panel:

```
RepeaterItem lastRepeaterItem = RT_Ranges.Items[RT_Ranges.Items.Count - 1];
Panel lastPanel = (Panel)lastRepeaterItem.FindControl("PanelID");
lastPanel.CssClass = "yourclass";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RT_Ranges" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div <%# (Container.DataItemIndex != 0 && (Container.DataItemIndex+1) % 4 == 0) ? @"class='myClass'" : @"class='item'" %>>
            <h4>
                <%# Eval("Category_Name")%></h4>
            <asp:Image ID="Image1" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Img") %>' runat="server" Height="92" Width="79" />
            <p>
                <%# Eval("des") %></p>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HL_More" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("nav") %>' runat="server">View More</asp:HyperLink>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Or using jQuery:

```
$("table.RT_Ranges div:last").attr("class", "last");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change class attribute value as follows,

```
        <div class="<%# GetItemClass(Container.ItemIndex) %>">
```

And create `GetItemClass` method in code behid,

```
protected string GetItemClass(int itemIndex)
{
    if (itemIndex == this.ItemCount - 1)
        return "last";
    else
        return "other";
}
```

Also refer 
[Change repeater li item class if first or last](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5263696/change-repeater-li-item-class-if-first-or-last)